# How to call UDF with Dapper?

Tags: sql-server, orm, sql-server-2008-r2, user-defined-functions, dapper

Is there any way to call table-valued UDF with Dapper, except:

```
var rows = connection.Query("select * from My_UDF(@a,@b)", new {a=1, b=2 });
```

I prefer to avoid magic strings hence I would like to use something similar to calling SP syntax.

I use MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. Dapper basically (with a few tweaks) follows the same rules as ADO.NET, and in both ADO.NET and raw TSQL, what you have posted is the *only* way of invoking a UDF - therefore, that remains the syntax used by dapper. Additionally, when calling a UDF you are required to specify the schema-name (typically `dbo.My_UDF`).